# Cannot connect to SQL Server 2014 from Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014

I have installed SQL Server 2014 as well as Management Studio. Than I have imported database from .bkp file and try to make connection. My connection string looks like this.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Name" 
         connectionString="server=PCNAME\SQLEXPRESS;database=DatabaseInMSSQL;User ID=sa;Password=password" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And this is error:

> Cannot open database \"DatabaseName\" requested by the login. The
>   login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'sa'

Here is the code that I am using to connect

```
public void OpenConnection()
{
    if (connection == null)
    {
        connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Name"].ConnectionString);
    }

    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        connection.Open();
    }
}
```

I can login normally as well as windows auth, and SQL Server Authentication in SQL Server Management Studio with that password and user. My firewall is temporarily off!

I am using VS 2013 Community edition, and Windows 8.1 64bit

Comment: SQL Express blocks remote TCP/IP connections by default. Try following the steps here and see if that works: http://support.webecs.com/kb/a868/how-do-i-configure-sql-server-express-to-allow-remote-tcp-ip-connections-on-port-1433.aspx

Comment: I have enabled TCP/IP

Comment: Maybe the issue is you need to enable dual mode authentication? Try the steps here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Sql Server and Windows Authentication mode is checked, btw thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that the user `sa` (which you should ***never ever*** use for any kind of work anyways!) has a *default* database set as `DatabaseName` which doesn't exist.

How to fix it?

- Login as `sa` or any other SQL Server system admin
- Go to `Object Explorer > Security > Logins > sa` and right-click and select `Properties`

[image]

- Change the default database for that user to something that **does** exist

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have changed that to DatabaseInMSSQL (name of database I am targeting, and restarted service, but still the same

Comment: @1392023093user: then you need to show us the code where you try to connect to the database server ...